# How can I prevent Entity Framework from adding duplicate entries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on an application for tracking workouts and the functionality I'm trying to add is so that a user can add a workout that has several related exercise records, where each record has an associated exercise. Each of these is modeled by a separate entity i.e. Workout, ExerciseRecord and Exercise with the following relations:

- Workout is related to many ExerciseRecords.
- ExerciseRecord is related to one Exercise.

I've also implemented a unit of work class and repositories for each entity (though I'm not sure whether this is necessary - I am quite new to ASP.Net MVC!).

My code for adding a workout looks as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(WorkoutViewModel viewModel)        
{        
    var exerciseRecordList = viewModel.ExerciseRecords;

    foreach (ExerciseRecord r in exerciseRecordList)
    {
        var e = exerciseList.Exercises
            .Where(ex => ex.ExerciseId == r.ExerciseId)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        r.Exercise = e;

        if (viewModel.WorkoutId != 0)
        {
            r.WorkoutId = viewModel.WorkoutId;
        }
    };

    Workout workout;

    if (viewModel.WorkoutId == 0)
    {
        workout = new Workout
        {
            WorkoutId = viewModel.WorkoutId,
            WorkoutDate = viewModel.WorkoutDate,
            Duration = viewModel.Duration,
            Exercises = exerciseRecordList
        };
    }
    else
    {
        workout = unitOfWork.WorkoutRepository.GetByID(viewModel.WorkoutId);
        workout.WorkoutDate = viewModel.WorkoutDate;
        workout.Duration = viewModel.Duration;
        workout.Exercises = exerciseRecordList;
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (workout.WorkoutId == 0)
        {
            unitOfWork.WorkoutRepository.Insert(workout);
            unitOfWork.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            unitOfWork.WorkoutRepository.Update(workout);
            unitOfWork.Save();
        }

        TempData["message"] = "Workout has been saved";
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
    else
    {
        // When there has been a problem with the workout data values
        TempData["message"] = "Unable to save workout";
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

This code sort of works when creating new workouts however it seems to add duplicate exercises to the database. I also cannot use this to edit existing workouts as I receive the following error:

*The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.ExerciseRecords_dbo.Exercises_ExerciseId". The conflict occurred in database "WorkoutTracker", table "dbo.Exercise", column 'ExerciseId'.
The statement has been terminated.*

I presume my issue is that despite the Exercise objects associated with each ExerciseRecord already existing in the database, they need to be attached to the context in order for the Entity Framework to be aware that they already exist.

Am I along the right track with this method or is there a much easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do which basically boils down to:

1. Create a Workout object
2. For each Workout, create *x* number of ExerciseRecord objects
3. For each ExerciseRecord object, associate a single existing Exercise object

Comment: Can you post your class structure for exercise, exerciserecord, and workout?

Comment: Find out what the ExerciseIds are before you try to save. The foreign key error implies that you are trying to insert an ExerciseId that does exist in dbo.Exercise table.

Comment: Can I safely assume that your `unitOfWork` uses one context instance for all repositories?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.

@Gregg - During the GET Edit method, the ViewModel is being set up correctly and linked to the correct WorkoutId and ExerciseRecords, however when I inspect the ViewModel during the POST Edit method, the ExerciseRecords are no longer linked to a Workout and have an ExerciseId of 0. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: @drneel - I can't paste the code unfortunately due to character restrictions but here is a summary:

**Workout** (int WorkoutId, DateTime Date, TimeSpan Duration, IList<ExerciseRecord> Exercises). **ExerciseRecord** (int ExerciseRecordId, int Reps, int Sets, decimal Weight, Exercise Exercise, int ExerciseId, Workout Workout, int WorkoutId). **Exercise** ( int ExerciseId, string ExerciseName, ExerciseCategory ExerciseCategory, int ExerciseCategoryId, MuscleGroup MuscleGroup, int MuscleGroupId).

Comment: @GertArnold - Yes it does. I used [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) as a guide.

Comment: @Gregg - I've just had a thought re: my previous comment. Could this be because I'm not including every field in my Edit view and it is therefore setting them to default values? If so, would it be best to include all fields and hide them in my view, or just re-set their values in the POST Edit method?

Comment: You can store fields that you need for the database but not the view in a hidden field.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't use comments for code. Also, I don't think this is about duplicates any more.

Comment: @GertArnold - The issue is still that I am ending up with duplicate Exercise entries when trying to create a new Workout however I believe this may then be having a knock on effect when trying to Edit existing Workouts. They could be two unrelated issues however I don't really know until I solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just discovered what the issue was. My Create/Edit view has a text box with autocomplete that allows the user to select an Exercise name. Upon selection this then sets the ExerciseId foreign key for the ExerciseRecord.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise.ExerciseName, new { @class = "autocomplete form-control", id = "", name = "ExerciseName_" + i, data_url = @Url.Action("AutoComplete") })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ExerciseRecords[i].ExerciseId, new { id = "" + i, name = "ExerciseId_" + i, @class = "hidden-id" })
```

There is a many-to-one relationship between ExerciseRecords and Exercises so an ExerciseRecord object has an ExerciseId foreign key as well as an Exercise object navigation property.

```
public class ExerciseRecord
{
    public int ExerciseRecordId { get; set; }
    public int Reps { get; set; }
    public int Sets { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; } 

    public virtual Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }

    public virtual Workout Workout { get; set; }  
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
}
```

What was happening was that when submitting the form, both the ExerciseId foreign key was set, as well as the associated Exercise.ExerciseName (but none of the other Exercise object fields). This seems to have been causing the Entity Framework to then create duplicate exercises using the ExerciseName that was set because all the other fields were set to null values or 0.

I have now amended this by changing the text box for the Exercise name in my Create/Edit view to the following:

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete form-control" id="" data-url=@Url.Action("AutoComplete") value=@(Model.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise == null?"":Model.ExerciseRecords[i].Exercise.ExerciseName)>
```

This still allows me to select an Exercise name and set the corresponding ExerciseId, however doesn't set the ExerciseName property of the associated Exercise object.

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in the order that what you are trying to do basically boils down to:

```
   //Find (or Create) a `Workout` entity
   if (viewModel.WorkoutId == 0)
   {
      workout = new Workout();
      unitOfWork.WorkoutRepository.Insert(workout);
      unitOfWork.SaveChanges();   //You need to save here to ensure the ID is set
   }
   else
   {
      workout = unitOfWork.WorkoutRepository.GetByID(viewModel.WorkoutId);
   }
   workout.WorkoutDate = viewModel.WorkoutDate;
   workout.Duration = viewModel.Duration;

   //You appear to already have a set of ExerciseRecords already 
   //linked to an Exercise, so now link them to the workout
   foreach (ExerciseRecord r in viewModel.ExerciseRecords)
   {

      //I can't work out why you are fetching Exercises by the
      //ExerciseRecord's ExerciseId then using that to set the Exercise
      //property. But I think that is why you are getting duplicates,
      //so I have removed that fetch. The foreign key is sufficient and it 
      //is already set
      r.WorkOutID = workout.ID; 
   };

    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

References:

[Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

[Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Colin. Would I also need to add some code in to insert/update the ExerciseRecords? If I try the code above it inserts a Workout object with no associated ExerciseRecords. So is it my understanding that you only need to set the foreign keys and EF should then figure out which object you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the first reference.